Test a ReadOnlySpan<char> at an index for a matching string
Given a ReadOnlySpan<char>, how can I confirm that a string exists at a given index in the span? I need a bool result.
I'd like a simple, preferably one line, zero allocation method.
My attempts quickly get tricky due to bounds checking, having to do math to calculate index offset to the end of the span, etc. My solutions are too verbose. I'd like to see if you can solve this really cleanly. Try to preserve the lambda syntax. Thanks.
var span = "FooBarBazBizzBuzz".AsSpan();
Assert.IsTrue(Test(span,9,"Bizz".AsSpan()));

// As you can see, I am trying to use parameters that have no allocation

public bool Test(ReadOnlySpan<char> span, int index, ReadOnlySpan<char> pattern) => //???;




Assume that the index is already tested to be within span.Length. Therefore, false will be returned if index+pattern.Length>span.Length that is a required bounds check.

You can get a slice of the span starting from index, and test StartsWith:
bool Test(ReadOnlySpan<char> span, int index, ReadOnlySpan<char> pattern) =>
    span[index..].StartsWith(pattern)

This compares the char values individually. There is another overload that takes a StringComparison as the second parameter.
If you don't want to return false when index is invalid, add a check:
bool Test(ReadOnlySpan<char> span, int index, ReadOnlySpan<char> pattern) =>
    index <= span.Length && index >= 0 && 
        span[index..].StartsWith(pattern);

